# How to apply modifier or view by condition

Tags: swiftui

```
@State var modifierEnabled : Bool

struct BlankModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
    }
}

extension View {
    func TestModifierView() -> some View{
       return self.modifier(BlankModifier())
    }
}
```

How to apply `TestModifierView` only in case of `modifierEnabled == true` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, content: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            content(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<TrueContent: View, FalseContent: View>(_ condition: Bool, ifTrue trueContent: (Self) -> TrueContent, else falseContent: (Self) -> FalseContent) -> some View {
        if condition {
            trueContent(self)
        } else {
            falseContent(self)
        }
    }
}
```

usage example ( one modifier ) :

```
Text("some Text")
   .if(modifierEnabled) { $0.foregroundColor(.Red) }
```

usage example2 (two modifier chains related to condition) :

```
Text("some Text")
   .if(modifierEnabled) { $0.foregroundColor(.red) } 
   else:                { $0.foregroundColor(.blue).background(Color.green) }
```

## BUT!!!!!!!!!!!

Important thing that this modifier can be reason of some indentity issues. (later you will understand this)

So in some cases better to use standard `if` construction

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution without type erasers. It looks strict and elegant.

```
public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func modify<TrueContent: View, FalseContent: View>(_ condition: Bool, ifTrue modificationForTrue: (Self) -> TrueContent, ifFalse modificationForFalse: (Self) -> FalseContent) -> some View {
        if condition {
            modificationForTrue(self)
        } else {
            modificationForFalse(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
HStack {
...
            }
            .modify(modifierEnabled) { v in
                    v.font(.title)
                } ifFalse: {
                    $0.background(Color.red) // even shorter
                }
```

If you only plan to apply a modifier (or a chain of modifiers) consider this:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func modifier<VM1: ViewModifier, VM2: ViewModifier>(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, applyIfTrue: VM1, applyIfFalse: VM2
) -> some View {
        if condition() {
           self.modifier(applyIfTrue)
        } else {
           self.modifier(applyIfFalse)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is almost as simple as with regular `.modifier`.

...

```
    Form {
        HStack {
...
            }
            .modifier(modifierEnabled, applyIfTrue: CornerRotateModifier(amount: 8, anchor: .bottomLeading), applyIfFalse: EmptyModifier())
```

...

You can omit `applyIfFalse` part for conciseness and just `return self.erase()` if condition is false.