# Conditionally searchable Table in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have the following view that is used in multiple different places in my app :

```
    var body: some View {
        Table(sortedResults, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            TableColumn("Key", value: \.key)
            TableColumn("Type", value: \.value.typeString)
            TableColumn("Value", value: \.value.valueString)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchString, prompt: "Search for a Key")
        .textSelection(.enabled)
    }
```

However, I sometimes don't want it to be `searchable` (for example when I know I'm displaying a very short list).

Is there a way to conditionally make `Table` searchable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply modifier or view by condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029560/how-to-apply-modifier-or-view-by-condition)

Comment: Yes I've seen that before but it seems like a bit of a hack - is there anything native to SwiftUI that supports this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a simple `ViewModifier`

```
struct OptionalSearchableViewModifier: ViewModifier{
    let isSearchable: Bool
    @Binding var searchString: String
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        switch isSearchable{
        case true:
            content
                .searchable(text: $searchString, prompt: "Search for a Key")
        case false:
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace

```
.searchable(text: $searchString, prompt: "Search for a Key")
```

with

```
.modifier(OptionalSearchableViewModifier(isSearchable: sortedResults.count >= 5, searchString: $searchString))
```