# How is Conditional Content created in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, conditional-statements, implementation, viewbuilder

I was trying to understand the inner workings of `_ConditionalContent` but I wasn't able to implement a resultBuilder for it. This is how some of the resultBuilders for `_ConditionalContent` are defined:

```swift
static func buildEither<T: View, F: View>(first: T) -> _ConditionalContent<T, F>
```

This doesn't make sense to me because how is `F` determined? It can't be type erased to `AnyView` because I have seen both type parameters be concrete SwiftUI views, eg. `_ConditionalContent<Text, Button>`. It only makes sense that in conjunction with the other `buildEither(second:)` function is the final type for `_ConditionalContent` determined.

I wasn't able to get a rough-cut version of this working so if anyone can explain to me how to implement this **using result builders** please let me know:

```swift
struct ConditionalConent<T: View, F: View> {
    let trueContent: T
    let falseContent: F
}

@resultBuilder
struct ConditionalContentBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<V: View>(_ content: V) -> V {
        return content
    }

    static func buildEither<T: View, F: View>(first: T) -> ConditionalContent<T, F> {
        // ... how is ConditionalContent created?
    }

    static func buildEither<T: View, F: View>(second: F) -> ConditionalContent<T, F> {
        // ... how is ConditionalContent created?
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001678/conditionally-searchable-table-in-swiftui/75001932#75001932

Comment: @loremipsum Hey, I saw the answer you linked and I still don't understand how the generic type parameters are determined. Even with an `isTrue` variable I don't see how both `trueContent` and `falseContent` can be initialised

Comment: I’m pretty sure result builder is for UIKit not SwiftUI never tried it through

Comment: If you jump to definition for `ViewBuilder` and search for `_ConditionalContent` in the SwiftUI module that pops up, you'll find a `ViewBuilder` extension that declares `buildEither` like I've shown above. Since `buildEither` is a result builder function I'm guessing result builder was also used for SwiftUI

Comment: SwiftUI is mostly UIKit underneath. There is a lot we don’t know about how it call comes together. Plausible, happy quest. I don’t think it is compatible. For the same reason that you can’t have arrays of views without destroying identity. I might be wrong…

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own `ConditionalAnimation` struct using a custom protocol called `Animation` (not `View`). I wanted to create a similar syntax to how SwiftUI `if-else` statements work. For that reason, I asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960740 hoping I could make progress to achieving that. Do you think this syntax is impossible to replicate? I don't necessarily care about `View`; I just thought that more people might have knowledge about it. I'm only trying to replicate how something can infer the type parameters when using result builder `if-else` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Result builders were officially defined by [SE-0289](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md). The section [Selection statements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md#selection-statements) describes how `if/else` statements are transformed. For your question, the answer is given by this sentence:

> Note that all of the assignments to `vMerged` will be type-checked together, which should allow any free generic arguments in the result types of the injections to be unified.

Normally, in Swift, each statement is type-checked independently of other statements, so the statements inside the two branches of `if/else` cannot influnce each others' type-checking. But in an `if/else` statement inside a result builder, where both of the branches assign the result to the same (synthesized) variable, Swift uses both branches together to infer the type of that variable.

This is similar to how both branches of a `?:` operator must have the same type. For example, using [your definition of `ConditionalContent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75962970/77567), we can write this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConditionalContent<T: View, F: View> {
    var condition: Condition

    enum Condition {
        case isTrue(T)
        case isFalse(F)
    }
}

let vMerged: ConditionalContent = 1 > 2
    ? .init(condition: .isTrue(Text("really big one")))
    : .init(condition: .isFalse(Text("normal sized one").opacity(0.5)))

print(type(of: vMerged))
// output: ConditionalContent<Text, ModifiedContent<Text, _OpacityEffect>>
```

Swift can infer the types for `T` and `F` by looking at both branches of the `?:` operator. A result builder performs a similar inference using both branches of an `if/else` statement.