# SwiftUI How can we add conditions to modifiers

Tags: swiftui

I would like to add the .controlSize modifier when the macOS version is 11 and new but I am having issues. How can I fix this issue

```
Button(action: {
    viewModel.getRoomId()
}, label: {
    Text("Get Pin")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(.all)
        .frame(height: 44)
    .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Make full button tappable
})
if #available(macOS 11, *) {
.controlSize(.large)
}
```

Comment: For a general approach, see https://davedelong.com/blog/2021/10/09/simplifying-backwards-compatibility-in-swift/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally searchable Table in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001678/conditionally-searchable-table-in-swiftui)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `controlSize` modifier itself is available before `macOS 11`, just not the `large` size.

You can define something like this:

```
@ViewBuilder
func largeControlSizeCompat() -> some View {
    if #available(macOS 11.0, *) {
        self.controlSize(.large)
    } else {
        self.controlSize(.regular)
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
Button("Test") { /* */ }
  .largeControlSizeCompat()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper for that modifier as a `View` extension:

```
extension View {
    
    func controlSizeIfAvailable(_ controlSize: ControlSize) -> some View {
        if #available(macOS 11, *) {
            return self.controlSize(controlSize)
        }
        else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
        Button(action: {
           viewModel.getRoomId() 
        }, label: {
            Text("Get Pin")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.all)
                .frame(height: 44)
            .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Make full button tappable
        })
        .controlSizeIfAvailable(.large)
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works as well but I can only select one answer.