# Swift - Pass a paremeter to a KeyPath

Tags: swift, viewmodifier, swift-keypath

SwiftUI modifiers don't allow passing optional values, and I'd really like to handle them in a clean way. E.g.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    let accessibilityValue: String?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Foo")
            .accessibilityValue(accessibilityValue)
    }
}
```

This won't work because `accessibilityValue` expects a non-`Optional` and I don't want to use `accessibilityValue ?? ""` because I'll lose the default `accessibilityValue`.

I want to call a function like

```swift
var body: some View {
    Text("Foo")
        .map(accessibilityValue, \.accessibilityValue)
}
```

When I try:

```swift
@ViewBuilder func map<T, Content: View>(_ value: T?,
                                        _ keyPath: KeyPath<Self, Content>) -> some View {
    if let value {
        self[keyPath: keyPath](value) // Error
    } else {
        self
    }
}
```

I get the error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'Content'`.

And when I try:

```swift
@ViewBuilder func map<T, Content: View>(_ value: T?,
                                        _ keyPath: KeyPath<Self, ((T) -> Content)>) -> some View {
    if let value {
        self[keyPath: keyPath](value)
    } else {
        self
    }
}
```

I get an error at the caller: `Key path cannot refer to instance method 'accessibilityValue'`.

Could I create a `KeyPath` to a `KeyPath`? That doesn't seem to make sense and I couldn't see how it's done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001678/conditionally-searchable-table-in-swiftui/75001932#75001932

Comment: @loremipsum it still doesn't give me a clean way to pass a parameter to a KeyPath. Using a solution like that is still the same amount of code/boilerplate, so it doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: It is just a way to accomplish  the optional  accessibility, the keypath thing doesn’t make sense. A key path refers to a variable and passing parameters is a term for function you can’t convert a String to a function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it seems that there's no answer here. `KeyPath` cannot any parameters.