How to conditionally apply an accessibility action?
SwiftUI has the handy .accessiblityAction() ViewModider that adds an accessibility action to a view that you are creating. Keyboard users and VO users can learn about the actions attached to the View and trigger them.
I want to be able to conditionally apply an action based on a boolean. Something like this:

Button {
    print("Button tapped")
} label: {
    Text("Button title")
}
if addActionToButton.wrappedValue {
    .accessibilityAction(named: "Button action") {
        print("Button action triggered")
    }
}

You can't put a ViewModifier like accessibilityAction inside an if statement however.
.accessibilityLabel has a variant that takes an isEnabled parameter. When the isEnabled condition is false, it does not apply the accessibility label:
@State addA11Label: Bool

Button {
    print("Button tapped")
} label: {
    Text("Button title")
}
.accessibilityLabel("Button foo. Double-tap to do stuff.", isEnabled: addA11Label.wrappedValue)

I want a accessibilityAction isEnabled parameter, but no such luck.
How could I conditionally add an accessibilityAction to my Button (or other view)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001678/conditionally-searchable-table-in-swiftui/75001932#75001932

What if you just did nothing in accessibilityAction? Does it have any other side effects?

@loremipsum I don't like that approach because it changes view identity, which can be undesirable.

Sweeper, adding an empty accessibilityAction is no good because VO and keyboard access still announce the (useless) accessibilityAction to the user and let them trigger it.

I don’t think you’ll find another approach

Actually, the accepted answer below does work. I must have had something wrong with the code I tried, because I got some totally cryptic compiler errors.

You could create a custom view extension that uses @ViewBuilder to add the action only when a specified Boolean is true.
Example:
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func conditionalAccessibilityAction(
        _ condition: Bool,
        name: String,
        perform action: @escaping () -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        if condition {
            self.accessibilityAction(named: name, perform: action)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var addActionToButton: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                print("Button tapped")
            } label: {
                Text("Button Title")
            }
            .conditionalAccessibilityAction(
                addActionToButton,
                name: "Button action"
            ) {
                print("Button action triggered")
            }
            
            Toggle("Add Accessibility Action", isOn: $addActionToButton)
                .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

The extension would check the boolean and apply .accessibilityAction(named:perform:) if the condition is met, otherwise it leaves the view unchanged.

I tried and could not get code like that to compile.

Is that tested code or just something you typed into the SO editor?

@DuncanC, Not tested, what error were you getting?

I couldn't work out the syntax in my attempt. I was getting very confusing compiler errors. I deleted my code, so don't have access to the errors any more. Your code works though. Thanks! (Accepted and voted.)

The errors you get from the LLVM Swift compiler are often shockingly bad. You'd think a compiler as smart as LLVM would be able to provide better info about what's wrong with your code. I hope Apple applies some of their "Apple Intelligence" to solving that problem.
